# Unable to load paramfile file://targets.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'targets.json'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Command Used:

```
aws events put-targets --rule my-rule_30min-CLI --targets file://targets.json
```

Error parsing parameter '--targets': Unable to load paramfile file://targets.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'targets.json'

Comment: Does the `targets.json` exist? Have you tried specifying full path for it if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its worked for the below command.

aws events put-targets --rule my-rule_30min-CLI --targets '{"Id" : "1", "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:setGlueParamCLI"}'